# how to make USP pendrive as bootable in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I wan to install solaris 10 along with Ubuntu 12.04.
But My question is how to make USP pendrive as bootable in ubuntu.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). You can install this using Software Center or Synaptic Package manager.